# Modify list to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How convert a list of email addresses to a dictionary,  where the keys are the usernames, and the values are the respective domains.

I did my code, but it did not give me right answer. What am I doing wrong? How to receive 3 keys and 3 values?

```
list1="harry@abc.com , larry@abc.ca , sally@abc.org "
list2=list1.split("@",3)
print({list2[i]:list2[i+1] for i in range(0,len(list2),2)})

>> {'harry': 'abc.com , larry', 'abc.ca , sally': 'abc.org '}
```

Comment: What language is this? You should always include the language in which you are coding as a tag on the question. It is far more important than the tags you chose to include. I think it's Python but I'm just guessing. Also instead of "enter code here" with backticks surrounding it, the sections of code should be enclosed in backticks or multiple lines of code can be surrounded by triple backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue here is that the value of `list1` is a string, not a list.
Your code should look like this:

```
list1 = ["harry@abc.com", "larry@abc.ca", "sally@abc.org"]
dict1 = {}
for email_address in list1:
    name_and_domain = email_address.split("@")
    name = name_and_domain[0]
    domain = name_and_domain[1]
    dict1[name] = domain
```

or if you must keep the value of `list1` as a string, you can convert it to a list by splitting it at each `,` like this:

```
string1 = "harry@abc.com,larry@abc.ca,sally@abc.org"
list1 = string1.split(',')
dict1 = {}
for email_address in list1:
    name_and_domain = email_address.split("@")
    name = name_and_domain[0]
    domain = name_and_domain[1]
    dict1[name] = domain
```

Comment: Thank you, I see that your code totally different than my, but also I understand how it works. Thank you for you help in comment too.

Comment: Or, as a one-liner: `dict(word.strip().split('@') for word in string1.split(','))`